# In Thunderbird, searching a word on the top field (Ctrl-K) lists me two messages extracts. But when I click on any, it doesn't show it

Tags: thunderbird

I'm using the *Thunderbird* that *Debian 12* currently maintains by default. It's the version `115.3` currently.

When I do a search on the top field of *Thunderbird*, where a `Crtl-K` is shown,
I type: `zeppelin`, and receive two responses:

[image]

But when I click on any response link, it displays:

[image]

How do I go to my e-mails to read them entirely?
What are their locations?

If the `Ctrl-K` feature doesn't have the purpose I believed it has (searching messages in folders), what its goal?

Comment: Testing with the BetterBird fork of Thunderbird that's based on TB 102 for Windows, clicking on a blue title does result in a set of messages matching the selected criteria. I would suggest therefore that the behaviour you see is a bug and should be reported as such. (Won't write this as a proper answer as I can't test with TB on Debian.)